# tag name property undefined using Vue but accessible within the browser

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Currently i have a selector that returns undefined when using Vue for the {{ lens.price }}. But when i use `a = lens[1].getAttribute('price')` within the browser console i get the correct returned value of `"0"`.

Why is Vue making this returned data undefined? The property works fine within the browser on all options that are returned from the for loop.

Do i need to pass both properties to a single value tag name?

HTML/LIQUID:

```
    <div>
      <label for="lens"></label>
      <select id="lens" name="line_items[lens]" @change="handleChange('lens', $event); secondChange($event);"
        class="mt-3 option-selector text-sm lg:text-base uppercase block appearance-none w-full bg-white text-gray-900 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded-sm leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-black font-bold">
        <option>Choose a lens</option>
        {% for lens in collections.lenses.products %}
        <option price="{{ lens.price }}" value="{{ lens.variants[0].id }}">{{ lens.title }} |
          {{ lens.price | plus: product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </select>
    </div>
```

BREAKDOWN OF VUE: (NOT COMPLETE CODE)

```
data: function () {
    return {
        buttonText: false,
        slideOut: false,
        disableAddToCart: true,
        chosenLens: '',
        chosenFilter: '',
        lensPrice: ''
    }

handleChange(type, e) {
        if (type === 'lens') {
            if (e.target.value) {
                this.chosenLens = e.target.value;
            }
            else {
                this.chosenLens = ''
            }
        }
        if (type === 'filter') {
            this.chosenFilter = e.target.value || ''
        }
        this.disableAddToCart = !(this.chosenLens && this.chosenFilter);
    },
    secondChange(e) {
        this.lensPrice = `${e.target.price}`;
    },
```

I have tried Javascript only: (undefined)

```
<div>
    <label for="lens"></label>
    <select id="lens" onchange="myFunction()" name="line_items[lens]" @change="handleChange('lens', $event);"
      class="mt-3 option-selector text-sm lg:text-base uppercase block appearance-none w-full bg-white text-gray-900 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded-sm leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-black font-bold">
    <option>Choose a lens</option>
    {% for lens in collections.lenses.products %}
    <option price="{{ lens.price }}" value="{{ lens.variants[0].id }}">{{ lens.title }} |
      {{ lens.price | plus: product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div >
    <h1 id="demo"></h1>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("lens").price;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
      }
</script>
```

Only attribute name 'value': (working)

```
    <div>
  <label for="lens"></label>
  <select id="lens" onchange="xIs()" name="line_items[lens]" @change="handleChange('lens', $event);"
    class="mt-3 option-selector text-sm lg:text-base uppercase block appearance-none w-full bg-white text-gray-900 py-3 px-4 pr-8 rounded-sm leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:border-black font-bold">
    <option>Choose a lens</option>
    {% for lens in collections.lenses.products %}
    <option value="{{ lens.price }}">{{ lens.title }} |
      {{ lens.price | plus: product.price | money_without_trailing_zeros}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
<h1 id="demo"></h1>
<script>
 const xIs = () => {
  var x = document.getElementById("lens").value;
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = `x is: ${x}`;
}

</script>
```

Comment: Just on curious, what's this syntax called `{% for lens in collections.lenses.products %}` in Vue?

Comment: That's liquid. The property values returned are as normal. I am just looking to get the returned values instead of undefined. As i said, the browser gets the data-price, although, Vue doesn't.

Comment: What's ```e.target``` value at that point of time? You might get undefined because it's not available anymore.

Comment: At that point using console.log only value on selection returns a value, the lens.price is instantly undefined. Both before setting this.lensPrice or after.

Comment: There's not enough context to see the problem. `lens` is defined both in your liquid template **and** the Vue template, but it's unclear how `lens` is defined in your Vue script.

Comment: I believe it maybe something else as if i do value="{{lens.price}}" i get returned the correct values. Only any other attribute name doesn't work.

Comment: Something else to what? How is `lens` defined in Vue's context?

Comment: this problem is mostly when your template is rendered before the data is populated, a simple trick would be to use a `v-if` around the element where you are printing the price. e.g. `v-fi=""lense && lense.price"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end i was successful with the same technique as the below.

```
<select id="app"  @change="deleteItem()">
      <option type="button" data-price="$149">
          $149
      </option>
      <option type="button" data-price="$409">
           $409
      </option>
    </select>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods:{
    deleteItem: function(){
        var carList = document.getElementById("app");
        var selCar = carList.options[carList.selectedIndex].dataset.price;
        alert(selCar)
    }
  },
})
```

The output is an alert of the data attribute of $149 on change or $409 on change. @click also works.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here:

```js
e.target.value
```

`e` is the browser event object.

`e.target` will be the `<select>` element.

A `<select>` element has a built-in property called `value` that reflects the currently selected value. This value is taken from the `value` attribute of the currently selected `<option>`.

So what happens is:

1. User clicks on an `<option>`.
2. The browser sets the `value` attribute of the `<select>` to be equal to the `value` attribute of the selected `<option>`.
3. The browser fires the `change` event for the `<select>`.

The `value` attribute has special significance in HTML. Other attributes of the `<option>`, such as `price`, do not.

Here's an example that doesn't use Vue at all that exhibits this same behaviour:

```js
document.getElementById('lens').addEventListener('change', function (ev) {
  const target = ev.target
  console.log(target.tagName, target.value, target.price)
})
```

```html
<select id="lens">
  <option value="A" price="1">First</option>
  <option value="B" price="2">Second</option>
</select>
```

Vue does have some special handling for binding non-string values to `<option>` elements for use with `v-model` but the problem you're seeing is not specific to Vue.

Comment: Thanks i'll do some more reading on the subject. I tried using the dataset attribute of data-price and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be a proper fix but i was able to just do a hack for now using split(): The problem is Vue seems to want data to come from Value and any other attribute name it didn't work with.

```
<option value="{{ filter.variants[0].id }}-{{ filter.price }}"><span>{{ filter.title }} +
  </span><span>{{ filter.price | money_without_trailing_zeros }}</span></option>

priceMethod(type, e) {
        if(type === 'lens')
        if (e.target.value) {
            let a = e.target.value
            a = a.split("-")[1]
            a = a.replace('00', '')
            console.log(a)
            a = parseInt(a)
            this.lensPrice = a;
        } 
        if (type === 'filter') {
            let b = e.target.value
                b = b.split("-")[1]
                b = b.replace('00', '')
                b = parseInt(b)
                console.log(b)
            this.filterPrice = b || ''
        }
```

Comment: It is standard behaviour for an HTML `<select>`, not specific to Vue. It is unclear why you would expect all of the attributes of the `<option>` to be magically copied across to the `<select>` when a value is chosen. From a Vue perspective the correct way to handle this would be to keep JS data as the source of truth rather than trying to store everything in the DOM. If you have the `value` as some sort of unique identifier then you can find the corresponding object within the original array. Or use `v-model` and Vue's special non-string `value` support to use objects as values.

Comment: Yes you are correct. It's not the correct way and i will try learn more to understand this.